# replace missing values using other rows only when other columns are the same in R

Tags: r, data.table

I guess that other people have already looked for it but couldn't find what I'm looking for.

I want to replace NA values with the value of the row above, only when all other values are the same. Bonus point for `data.table` solution.

Right now, I've managed to do it only with a (very inefficient) loop.

In addition, my current code does not replace NA in case that there are two NA's in the same row.

I have a strong feeling that I'm overthinking this problem. Any ideas of making this stuff easier?

```
ex <- data.table(
    id = c(1, 1, 2, 2),
    attr1 = c(NA, NA, 3, 3),
    attr2 = c(2, 2, NA, 3),
    attr3 = c(NA, 2, 2, 1),
    attr4 = c(1, 1, 1, 3)
)

desired_ex <- data.table(
    id = c(1, 1, 2, 2),
    attr1 = c(NA, NA, 3, 3),
    attr2 = c(2, 2, NA, 3),
    attr3 = c(2, 2, 2, 1),
    attr4 = c(1, 1, 1, 3)
)

col_names <- paste0("attr", 1:4)
r<-1
for (r in 1:nrow(ex)) {
    print(r)
    to_check <- col_names[colSums(is.na(ex[r, .SD, .SDcols = col_names])) >0]
    if (length(to_check) == 0) {
        print("no NA- next")
        next
    }
    
    for (col_check in to_check) {
        .ex <- copy(ex)[seq(from = r, to = r + 1), ]
        .ex[[col_check]] <- NULL
        if (nrow(unique(.ex)) == 1) {
            ex[[col_check]][r] <- ex[[col_check]][r + 1]
        }
    }
}

all.equal(ex, desired_ex)
```

Comment: I am not really sure what you want to do. Can you please explain in more detail? For example, why in `desired_ex` `attr2` has an `NA` but it is replaced in the `attr3`?

Comment: Look at rows `1:2`, apart from the `NA` in `attr3`, they are the same. Thus I would like to replace the `NA` with the value in the other line.
However, this is not the case for rows `3:4`, 
I see them as different rows, as apart from the `NA` in `attr2`, they differ in `attr3` and `attr4`.

Does it make more sense now?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which will work for an arbitrary number of rows and columns within each `id` not just pairs of rows:

```
library(data.table)
ex[,  
   if (all(unlist(lapply(.SD, \(x) all(first(x) == x, na.rm = TRUE))))) {
     lapply(.SD, \(x) rep(fcoalesce(as.list(x)), .N)) 
   } else {
     .SD
   }, by  = id]
```

or, more compact,

```
ex[, if (all(unlist(lapply(.SD, \(x) all(first(x) == x, na.rm = TRUE))))) 
  lapply(.SD, \(x) rep(fcoalesce(as.list(x)), .N)) else .SD, by  = id]
```

> ```
>    id attr1 attr2 attr3 attr4
> 1:  1    NA     2     2     1
> 2:  1    NA     2     2     1
> 3:  2     3    NA     2     1
> 4:  2     3     3     1     3
> ```

#### Explanation

*For each `id`* it is checked if the rows fulfill the condition. If *not* `.SD` is returned unchanged. If the condition is fulfilled a new `.SD` is created by picking the first non-NA value *in each column* (or `NA` in case of all `NA`) using `fcoalesce()` and replicating this value as many times as there are rows in `.SD`.

The check for the condition consists of 2 parts. First, it is checked *for each column* in `.SD` if all values are identical thereby ignoring any `NA`. Finally, it is checked if this is `TRUE` for all columns.

Note that `.SD` is a `data.table` containing the **S**ubset of **D**ata for each group, excluding any columns used in `by`.

#### Another use case with more rows and columns

```
ex2 <- fread("
 id   foo   bar   baz attr4 attr5
  1    NA     2    NA     1     5
  1    NA     2     2     1    NA
  1    NA     2    NA    NA    NA
  2     3    NA     2     1     2
  2     3     3     1     3     2
  2     3     3     1     4     2
  3     5     2    NA     1     3
  3    NA     2     2     1     3
  4    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
")

ex2[, if (sum(unlist(lapply(.SD, \(x) all(first(x) == x, na.rm = TRUE)))) == ncol(.SD)) 
  lapply(.SD, \(x) rep(fcoalesce(as.list(x)), .N)) else .SD, by  = id]
```

> ```
>    id foo bar baz attr4 attr5
> 1:  1  NA   2   2     1     5
> 2:  1  NA   2   2     1     5
> 3:  1  NA   2   2     1     5
> 4:  2   3  NA   2     1     2
> 5:  2   3   3   1     3     2
> 6:  2   3   3   1     4     2
> 7:  3   5   2   2     1     3
> 8:  3   5   2   2     1     3
> 9:  4  NA  NA  NA    NA    NA
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option mixing base R with data.table:

```
#lead the values for comparison
cols <- paste0("attr", 1L:4L)
lcols <- paste0("lead_", cols)
ex[, (lcols) := shift(.SD, -1L), id]

#check which rows fulfill the criteria
flags <- apply(ex[, ..cols] == ex[, ..lcols], 1L, all, na.rm=TRUE) & 
    apply(ex[, ..lcols], 1L, function(x) !all(is.na(x)))

#update those rows with values from row below
ex[(flags), (cols) := 
    mapply(function(x, y) fcoalesce(x, y), mget(lcols), mget(cols), SIMPLIFY=FALSE)]
ex[, (lcols) := NULL][]
```

Solution assumes that there is no recursive populating where the row after next is used to fill the current row if criteria is met.